# java two loops then change state

Tags: java, for-loop

i am trying to run this loop twice then change the state to 1. (state=1;). is that possible?

```
public void mousePressed() {
    if (state == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if (mouseX >= cards[i].x && mouseX <= cards[i].x + cards[i].WIDTH && mouseY >= cards[i].y && mouseY <= cards[i].y + cards[i].HEIGHT) {
                cards[i].flip();
            }
        }
state = 1;
}
```

Now when i run this loop it only run once and change state form 0 (state==0) to 1. My question is can i make this loop run twice (press the mouse 2 times) then change state from 0 to 1 (state=1;).

thank you very much in advance. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of using this crazy condition logic, simply get the component from the mouseevent and perform the necessary logic on it.

Comment: You could use states 0,1, and 2.

Comment: Why not call this method two times.

Comment: Can't you simply surround it by a loop that does it twice and then change state?

Comment: You mean, double click on the component the this loop runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gather that you want to change to state 1 on the second execution of `mousePressed`. You need to split your state. One way is to introduce a new state variable (let's call it `first`) that is used to distinguish between `state == 0` before and after the first mouse click:

```
private boolean first = true;
public void mousePressed() {
    if (state == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if (mouseX >= cards[i].x && mouseX <= cards[i].x + cards[i].WIDTH && mouseY >= cards[i].y && mouseY <= cards[i].y + cards[i].HEIGHT) {
                cards[i].flip();
            }
        }
        if (first) {
            first = false;;
        } else {
            state = 1;
            // perhaps reset first?
        }
    }
}
```

A second approach is to allow `state` to take on a third value that is treated the same as state 0 everywhere else in your logic. (Conceptually, you would have states 0 and 0'.)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are asking, is it something like that:

```
public void mousePressed() {
    state = 0; /* Assuming it is global */
    while (state < 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if (mouseX >= cards[i].x && mouseX <= cards[i].x + cards[i].WIDTH && mouseY >= cards[i].y && mouseY <= cards[i].y + cards[i].HEIGHT) {
                cards[i].flip();
            }
        state++;
    }
}
```

This will run the loop 2 times for each time `mousePressed` is called. switch `if` by `while`

Comment: thanks a lot for this answer. state++ will keep increasing state. I was looking for something that change state to 1 i.e state=1;. but thank you again for your answer.